# Append to same line using grep

Tags: unix, grep

I have a file with multiple lines. I'm trying to find lines that match a certain pattern and then get them appended to an output file, all on the same.

Ex:
Input file:

```
ABCD 
other text
EFGH
other text
IJKLM
```

I'm trying to get the output to be :

```
ABCD EFGH IJKLM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to make `grep` output matches separated by spaces instead of newlines is to wrap it in a sub-shell with `$(...)` like this:

```
echo $(grep -o '^[A-Z]*$' input.txt) >> output.txt
```

Or you could use `tr`:

```
grep -o '^[A-Z]*$' input.txt | tr '\n' ' ' >> output.txt
```

Or `perl`:

```
grep -o '^[A-Z]*$' input.txt | perl -pe 'chomp; s/$/ /'
```

Comment: Thanks! this looks like the easiest way for me to get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr` to translate the newlines to spaces:

```
grep $EXPRESSION $INPUT_FILE | tr '\n' ' ' >> $OUTPUT_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like perl, you can also

```
perl -nl40e 'print if /PATTERN/' files....
```

like

```
perl -nl40e 'print if /[A-Z]/' file
```

for your input produces

> ABCD EFGH IJKLM

Answer (score 0):

Here is an short `awk`

```
awk 'NR%2==1' ORS=" " file
ABCD EFGH IJKLM
```

It will print every second line into one line.